# Copy Aws launch template to another region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to know if it is possible to copy the launch template create in one region to another region.

The idea behind this is, if for some reason the region goes down, I would like to start my service in another region with this launch template.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot copy the launch template to another region, however, you can use aws cli to get launch template data and then create a template in the target region with the launch template details

Get: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/get-launch-template-data.html

Create: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-launch-template.html

Comment: do I need to modify the queried json content with the new region?

Comment: If your template specifies an AMI, you will need to change that and you may need to copy the existing AMI if it is a custom one.